# Is there a way to get city or block location in flutter without using gps (only wifi and/or cell towers)

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, android-gps

I am working on a flutter projet, and i need to know the approximative location of the user. I added the correct permission in the android manifest.
I tried using geolocator plugin but when i run the code below, it request the gps activation.

```
var loc = await GeolocatorPlatform.instance 
     .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
```

And the code below don't do anything at all

```
var loc = await GeolocatorPlatform.instance 
     .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.lowest);
```

How can i get the current position only using wifi or/and cell towers ? Can this plugin do that ?

Comment: You can use any api, forexample https://ip-api.com/